# Create another module in Compose Multiplatform Project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, multi-module, compose-multiplatform

I'm currently building a project with Compose Multiplatform, and I'm wondering to make this project structured with multi-module clean architecture.

Here's my current modules:

[image: My current modules]

**I'm looking for adding `:core` module in `:composeApp` module.**

[image: Add module window]

But it seems no option for Compose Multiplatform regular module (yet)

**How can I create module similar to `:commonMain`? Besides, I don't found any `include(':moduleName')` in `settings.gradle`**

Answer (score 0):

`commonMain` isn't a module, it is a source set in your `:composeApp` module. This is where you write your Kotlin code without access to Java standard libraries.

If you want to create another KMM module, you should use the last option in your template `Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module`. This will create a separate kmm gradle module which will also have `commonMain` inside of it.

Comment: For some weird reason, this option is no longer available in `Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new multiplatform module inside composeApp module.

Instead you can create a new module say 'core' inside your project by selecting 'Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module' as seen in the screenshot.

Now this 'core' module will be having all your source sets-
commonMain
androidMain
iosMain